# Paperclip custom processor not changing image type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm having a few problems with a paperclip custom processor.

At the command line this line :

```
$ convert cats.jpg -thumbnail 300x400  -bordercolor white -background black  +polaroid  cats.png
```

Successfully converts this :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4233433/cats.jpg

Into this :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4233433/cats.png

i.e a JPEG converted into a PNG with a transparent background. Which is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

However when I attempt to do this within Rails (4.0.1) using Paperclip I end up with :

[Link posted in comment]

It's renamed as a PNG but is actually a JPEG.

My model :

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :photo,
              processors: [:polarize],
              styles: {
                polarized: {
                  format: 'png',
                  is_polarized: true
                }
              } 

    belongs_to :user
end
```

And my processor :

```
module Paperclip
  class Polarize < Processor
    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      @file           = file
      @attachment     = attachment
      @is_polarized   = options[:is_polarized]
      @current_format = File.extname(@file.path) 
      @format         = options[:format]
      @basename       = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
    end

    def make
      temp_file = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
      temp_file.binmode

      if @is_polarized
        run_string =  "convert #{fromfile} -thumbnail 300x400  -bordercolor white -background white  +polaroid  #{tofile(temp_file)}"    
        Paperclip.run(run_string)
      end

      temp_file
    end

    def fromfile
      File.expand_path(@file.path)
    end

    def tofile(destination)
      File.expand_path(destination.path)
    end
   end
 end
```

In my Database `photo_content_type` is `image/jpeg` and `photo_file_name` is `cats.jpg` when I would have expected `image/png` and `cats.png` respectively. Any ideas?

UPDATE

The error was in this line

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
```

changing it to

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])
```

fixes things. Credit to shaun-frost-duke-jackson

Comment: Link to 3rd image : 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4233433/cats-1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation on the website but pretty sure it should be like below:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => ["32x32#", :png] }
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Under post processing

Guess your issue is here:

```
@format         = options[:format]
@basename       = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
temp_file = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the documentation. It's not a problem to change the format of an image using one of the standard processor (such as :thumb you mentioned above) the problem is doing it within a custom processor.

Comment: Your format will change because you have a join with :format and basename, pretty sure thats where your problem lies, have you tried changing it...

Comment: Bingo. The problem was with the `Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))` command. 

`[@basename, @format].compact.join(".")` on it's own creates what you would expect `filename.ext`, but then Tempfile adds on some random chararters after the extension. `Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])` works. Thanks.